# Trivial and nontrivial GCD of polynomials

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

What is the difference between trivial and non-trivial GCDs of two polynomials: $f,g$ where $f,g \in Q[x]$? I know if  $f,g \in Z[x]$, the only non-trivial GCD is 1, and everything else is trivial. Does this also apply for Q[x]?

Comment: What is a "trivial" GCD?  Does it mean unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all $a\in \Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ are units in $\Bbb Q[x]$, the trivial GCD's in $\Bbb Q[x]$ are the non-zero constants.